# How do i get input values in a view that has multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a view that will have multiple forms based on the number of documents in the model. Each form will contain hidden inputs and a file control for uploading a file and a submit button to upload the file.

i desire to use an ajax call to submit the form how ever i am having issues getting the input values using javascript.

My View

```
  @if (Model.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var document in Model)
        {
            var formId = i;
            var documentTypeIdInput = formId + "_documentTypeId";
            var accreditationApplicationIdInput = formId + "_accreditationApplicationId";
            var actionInput = formId + "_action";


            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header text-left">
                    <b> @($"{i} . {document.TypeDocumentDescription}")  </b>

                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>
                        <table class="table  table-sm  text-left">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Upload Date</th>
                                    <th>File </th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                @foreach (var uploadDoc in document.UploadedDocuments)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>@uploadDoc.CreateDate</td>
                                        <td>@uploadDoc.FileName</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="accordion-edit-btn" title="download file" target="_blank" asp-action="Download" asp-route-id="@uploadDoc.Id"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a>
                                            <a class="accordion-delist-btn" title="delete file" target="_blank" asp-action="DeleteFile" asp-route-id="@uploadDoc.Id" asp-route-actionOfOrigin="AddDocuments"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">

                                        <form id="@formId" class="form" action="UploadDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="documentTypeId" id="@documentTypeIdInput" asp-for="@document.DocumentTypeId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="accreditationApplicationId" id="@accreditationApplicationIdInput" asp-for="@document.AccreditationApplicationId" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="@actionInput" value="AddDocuments" />
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                                                @* add validation summary per document *@
                                                <button type="submit" title="upload document" class="btn btn-primary rounded submit"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> &nbsp; Upload File</button>
                                                @*  *@
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
            i++;


        }
    }
```

and my javascript sample

```
  $(".submit").on("click", (e) => {
            var $form = $(this).closest(".form");
            var formId = $(this).closest('form').attr("id");

            $form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                
                alert($("#" + formId + "_documentTypeId").val());
                
            }) 
        })
```

on my javascript i cant get the id of the form or the value of the input from the form which i am submitting, how do i accomplish this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `submit` event listener in the click event of the submit button seems odd.

Why not simply:

```
$(".form").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const formData = new FormData(this);
    alert(formData.get("documentTypeId");
});
```

You can easily send [the `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) via jQuery's `ajax` method, or using [the `fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).